# Arch equivalent of Debian `dpkg-divert`

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, skype

I am trying to configure Skype on Arch Linux to use a [sand boxed user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/skype#Use_Skype_with_special_user) no matter which user calls `skype`, but I don't particularly like the use of a BASH alias to launch Skype as suggested by the wiki since as far as I can tell if a user is not using BASH or invokes Skype from `skype.desktop`, the sand boxed user will not be used. I thought it might be better to divert `/usr/bin/skype` to call

```
sudo -u skype /usr/bin/skype.real
```

where `skype.real` is the actual Skype binary. I am pretty sure in Debian I could do this with

```
dpkg-divert --package skype --add --rename --divert /usr/sbin/skype.real /usr/sbin/skype
```

and then add my own file to `/usr/sbin/skype`. How do I do this with Arch?

Comment: Does `skype-restricted` not work? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/skype-restricted/

Comment: @Darkhogg I haven't tried it, but I am more interest in the general question of how to modify package files.

Comment: I think that using `PKGBUILD`s is probably the more general you can get on Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as I suggested on the comments, the `skype-restricted` AUR package is not suitable for you (and note that I don't know the approach they use), I can think of two approaches:

(Read to the end for the correct way of applying them on Arch)

#### Change `skype` to a script that runs your real Skype

Create a bash script that will call your real Skype:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u skype /usr/bin/skype.real
```

Give it execute permissions and save it as `/usr/bin/skype`, renaming the old Skype binary to `/usr/bin/skype.real`.

This approach leads a few things that needs consideration though:

- If you really want noone calling Skype (the real one) other than the `skype` user, you need to give the file the appropriate permissions:

  ```
  chown skype /usr/bin/skype.real
  chmod 0100 /usr/bin/skype.real
  ```

  This will avoid anyone but its owner to run it
- In order to let anyone run `skype` (the new, scripted one), you need to edit the sudoers file (using `visudo`) so anyone (preferrably in a group, possibly group `skype`) can call it as user `skype`. I don't know the details, I just know it can be done.

#### Change `skype` owner and set the `setuid` bit

*Note: This is not the recommended way, as setuid executables should be set to a minimum*

This migh be cleaner possibility can be setting the `setuid` bit so anyone calling `skype` calls it as the user `skype`.

```
chown skype /usr/bin/skype
chmod u+s /usr/bin/skype
```

This will make the `skype` command available as always, but it will always be run as the `skype` user.

---

**In any of the above cases**, any time you update Skype to a newer version you will need to repeat the process, as `pacman` will replace the binary.

The solution is to create a `PKGBUILD` that downloads the official package, extracts it and performs the desired changes. Then you install it manually (as you would install any AUR package). You will need to re-build it manually any time you need to update. Skype doesn't update that often though.

For this las one task, the [official wiki on PKGBUILDs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) are a great resource.

Comment: Downvote for suggesting an additional setuid binary/script (these should be kept to a minimum). `sudo` with `/etc/sudoers` is perfectly capable providing the ability to execute the given `/usr/bin/skype.real` without password and always as user `skype` with the script method.

Comment: You have the right idea, but recommending users manually move files around is a bad idea. Creating a custom `PKGBUILD` is absolutely the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @HalosGhost I edited my answer to highligh the use of a PKGBUILD.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I added a warning about it not being recommended. I will not remove it, though: It is another method, and is not incorrect, even if its not the best way.

Comment: I feel like you should rewrite your answer so that the only thing you recommend is creating a PKGBUILD. Then, the rest of what you offer in your answer, you should frame as being a part of a PKGBUILD. At the moment, you still offer using a PKGBUILD as an after-thought and solution to a separate issue.

Comment: @HalosGhost Although the question is Arch-specific, I don't feel the answer should be *that* Arch-specific, as the problem can arise in any distro. I also don't know how to create a PKGBUILD for the task, so feel free to add that as a different answer.

Comment: An Arch-specific question promotes an Arch-specific answer. But, even if it didn't, Linux distros use package managers so that users don't have to go mucking around with system files on their own. The solution for any distro is to create a new package; it just happens to be easier on Arch than on other distros because `PKGBUILD`s are written in Bash. Either way, the package you pointed out in your initial comment is probably what the OP should use (albeit, updated).

Comment: I think the top part of the answer is helpful, but not what I am looking for. It is the PKGBUILD that implements whatever the chosen strategy is that I don't understand how to create.

Comment: @Darkhogg: removed my downvote. Yes, it's not incorrect, but it's bad practice. Again `sudo` can deliver that in conjunction with the script you've already offered.